# iframe pull out a full screen photo

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need your help.
I have the code ready: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img
It works all right for me.
But I don't know the html markup. And I need the picture to open full screen. Not `<iframe>`.
For that I don't know. How would I get it out of `<iframe>` full screen.

```
<iframe width="468" height="60" allowTransparency></iframe>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is not clear what you mean _not iFrame_  and _out of iframe_ 
Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+modal+iframe+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan, Hello. I am missing these buttons

Comment: Click [edit], then `[<>]` in that editor

Answer (score 0):

Use a css property to cover up your background image.

`background-image: cover;`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).